In React/Next.js after click link data will not updated
In Next.js when clicking Link the new page url will open "/component/product", but according to product data will not updated in redux store where I used. It have to refresh page to update state data.
import Link from "next/link";

<Link href="/component/product">All Products</Link>

//redux state
const { products } = useSelector(state => state.products);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getProducts());
}, [dispatch, products])

Issue solved by useEffect but another issue is getProducts() continuously sending API request to server. Server will be consume more memory & more load time.
How to update data without refreshing page or stop continuous sending API request in useEffect?

Don't unconditionally fetch the products. The useEffect hook dispatches the getProducts action after the initial render cycle and anytime any of the dependencies update, e.g. products is likely a new reference each render cycle because it's fetched each render cycle and triggers the effect callback.

Remove products from the dependency array
const { products } = useSelector(state => state.products);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getProducts());
}, [dispatch]);


Only fetch products under a condition, e.g. if products is falsey or empty array
const { products } = useSelector(state => state.products);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!products?.length) {
    dispatch(getProducts());
  }
}, [dispatch, products]);



See also Equality Comparisons and Updates, you can likely use the shallowEqual helper function to run the selector function less often and provide a more stable products reference if necessary.
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const selectProducts = state => state.products;

...

const { products } = useSelector(selectProducts, shallowEqual);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!products?.length) {
    dispatch(getProducts());
  }
}, [dispatch, products]);

